# Xamarin How to add custom listview to fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin Android. I would like to ask on how to apply custom listview to a fragment. I've created one activity that holds a ListView, I then created another view for the custom elements that would be applied to the listview. I have a custom adapter and I have a fragment that I am trying to apply the custom listview but I'm receiving a null as shown below:

```
public class PeopleFragment : Fragment
{

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PeoplesCustomView, container, false);
        var peopleList = GetList();
        // Below code listView is null 
        var listView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.standardListView);
        listView.Adapter = new TestAdapter(this, peopleList);

        return view;

    }
}
```

Could this be due to the view on the first line when inflating to resource layout 'PeopleCustomView' it looks at this view to find an id of "standardListview"?
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the source code of `Resource.Layout.PeoplesCustomView ` layout as well?

Comment: Have done now, please check. Thanks

Comment: What you are seeing is PeoplesCustomView which is the custom view for the listview to be adapted. What your asking is in my layout file which contains a simple list view with an ID of standardListView

Comment: @helloworld if `view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.standardListView);` *returns* null, either `PeoplesCustomView` does not contain `standardListView` or the resource ids did not re-gen properly (perform a clean all / build all and debug again), or is `view` null?

Comment: That's why I asked about the source code of `Resource.Layout.PeoplesCustomView` (axml file), where I wanted to check if there're `Resource.Id.standardListView` available.

Comment: @Micer Am i not right to say that in the custom view it shouldn't contain a list view as this only specifies a single item of a list design i.e. text, image and etc. Then have a separate view that has a listview which contains the ID. Then you call adapter to this list to populate custom view onto the listview. i hope that made sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PeoplesCustomView should be your Fragment layout, not the layout for your list row.

For example:
Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        class="fragmentListview.Fragment1"
        android:id="@+id/titles_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/standardListView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment1.cs

```
public class Fragment1 : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListItem, container, false);

        var listView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.standardListView);
        listView.Adapter = new TestAdapter(this.Context as Activity);

        return view;            
    }
}
```

TestAdapter.cs

```
public class TestAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    List<string> _List = new List<string>();
    Activity _activity;

    public TestAdapter(Activity activity)
    {
        _activity = activity;
        FillContacts();
    }

    public override int Count => _List.Count;

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return _List[position];
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView ?? _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(
    Resource.Layout.ListItem, parent, false);
        var ListText = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ListText);
        var ListImage = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ListImage);
        ListText.Text = _List[position];

        return view;
    }

    void FillContacts()
    {
        _List.Add("First");
        _List.Add("Second");
        _List.Add("Third");
    }
}
```

ListItem.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ListImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I can see your solution is almost the same as mine but the only difference is that you created your fragment Declaratively (direct within .axml layout by using the <Fragment> tag) where as I have hosted fragment Programmatically (instantiated by using Fragment Manager). But this shouldn't make any difference based on the approach taken on creating Fragment. Apart from that, i can see mine is pretty much the same but still no hope :( are you able to provide a repo link with a solution and it uses Fragment Manager rather than declaring via xaml of the class?

Comment: As I said in the reply, you should use the layout for fragment in  `inflater.Inflate`; In your case it should be`var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PeopleStandardListViewLayout, container, false);` `standardListView` is not in the `PeoplesCustomView` so it is null.

Comment: @BillyLiu-MSFT it i have any delete action in listview how to manage that?
can i handle that event into the fragment?